# Is it not possible to create a postgres cloudsql via deployment manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-deployment-manager

I've check in [supported-gcp-types](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types) and [supported-resource-types](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) but I don't see any possibility at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deployment Manager supports PostgreSQL.

You need to specify the `backendType` as `SECOND_GEN`,  `databaseVersion` as `POSTGRES_9_6` and `tier` as `db-custom-1-3840`.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances)

Example (create-postgresql-instance.jinja):

```
{% set deployment_name = env['deployment']  %}
{% set instance_name = deployment_name + '-instance'  %}
{% set database_name = deployment_name + '-db'  %}
{% set region = 'us-central1'  %}
{% set tier = 'db-custom-1-3840'  %}

resources:
- name: {{ instance_name }}
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances
  properties:
    region: {{ region }}
    backendType: SECOND_GEN
    databaseVersion: POSTGRES_9_6
    settings:
      tier: {{ tier }}
      backupConfiguration:
        enabled: true

- name: {{ database_name }}
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:databases
  properties:
    name: {{ database_name }}
    instance: $(ref.{{ instance_name }}.name)
    charset: utf8
```

Deploy:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create mydb --template create-postgresql-instance.jinja
```

Comment: do you know how can we set the password for default postgres user?

Comment: @NikhilGupta - Create a new question with details.

Comment: @NikhilGupta this is simple enough - you set the root password with the `rootPassword` property. Put this just after `databaseVersion`:

rootPassword: {{ postgres_root_passwd }}` and add a variable up top that reads from env to get the password.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment manager Jinja template for PostgresSQL

```
{% set deployment_name = env['deployment']  %}
{% set instance_name = deployment_name + '-instance'  %}
{% set database_name = deployment_name + '-db'  %}
{% set region = 'us-central1'  %}
{% set tier = 'db-n1-standard-1'  %}
{% set databaseVersion = 'POSTGRES_11' %}
resources:
- name: {{ instance_name }}
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:instances
  properties:
      region: us-central1
      databaseVersion: POSTGRES_9_6
      instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
      settings:
        tier: db-f1-micro
        backupConfiguration:
          startTime: '02:00'
          enabled: true
        locationPreference:
          zone: us-central1-c

- name: {{ database_name }}
  type: gcp-types/sqladmin-v1beta4:databases
  properties:
    name: {{ database_name }}
    databaseVersion: POSTGRES_12
    instance: $(ref.{{ instance_name }}.name)
    charset: utf8
```